# Passed a 2D Array to another class but can't get the object returned

Tags: java, android, android-studio, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I'm currently developing an algorithm for my Tictactoe Android App (using Java) with Minimax, but first, I just want to make sure the algorithm works, so I made the algorithm to "suggests" the next move to the player.

The player is declared as `String player = "x";` in the Minimax class.

> Minimax.java

```
package com.firaz.tictactoe;

public class Minimax {
    public static class Move {
        int row, col;
    }

    static String player = "x";
    static String opponent = "o";
    String[][] board = new String[3][3];

    // This function returns true if there are moves
// remaining on the board. It returns false if
// there are no moves left to play.
    static Boolean isMovesLeft(String[][] board) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                if (board[i][j].equals("_"))
                    return true;
        return false;
    }

    // This is the evaluation function
    static int evaluate(String[][] b) {
        // Checking for Rows for X or O victory.
        for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
            if (b[row][0].equals(b[row][1]) &&
                    b[row][1].equals(b[row][2])) {
                if (b[row][0].equals(player))
                    return +10;
                else if (b[row][0].equals(opponent))
                    return -10;
            }
        }

        // Checking for Columns for X or O victory.
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
            if (b[0][col].equals(b[1][col])
                    && b[1][col].equals(b[2][col])) {
                if (b[0][col].equals(player))
                    return +10;

                else if (b[0][col].equals(opponent))
                    return -10;
            }
        }

        // Checking for Diagonals for X or O victory.
        if (b[0][0].equals(b[1][1])
                && b[1][1].equals(b[2][2])) {
            if (b[0][0].equals(player))
                return +10;
            else if (b[0][0].equals(opponent))
                return -10;
        }

        if (b[0][2].equals(b[1][1])
                && b[1][1].equals(b[2][0])) {
            if (b[0][2].equals(player))
                return +10;
            else if (b[0][2].equals(opponent))
                return -10;
        }

        // Else if none of them have won then return 0
        return 0;
    }

    // This is the minimax function. It considers all
// the possible ways the game can go and returns
// the value of the board
    static int minimax(String[][] board,
                       int depth, Boolean isMax) {
        int score = evaluate(board);

        // If Maximizer has won the game
        // return his/her evaluated score
        if (score == 10)
            return score;

        // If Minimizer has won the game
        // return his/her evaluated score
        if (score == -10)
            return score;

        // If there are no more moves and
        // no winner then it is a tie
        if (isMovesLeft(board) == false)
            return 0;

        // If this maximizer's move
        if (isMax) {
            int best = -1000;

            // Traverse all cells
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    // Check if cell is empty
                    if (board[i][j].equals("_")) {
                        // Make the move
                        board[i][j] = player;

                        // Call minimax recursively and choose
                        // the maximum value
                        best = Math.max(best, minimax(board,
                                depth + 1, !isMax));

                        // Undo the move
                        board[i][j] = "_";
                    }
                }
            }
            return best;
        }

        // If this minimizer's move
        else {
            int best = 1000;

            // Traverse all cells
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    // Check if cell is empty
                    if (board[i][j].equals("_")) {
                        // Make the move
                        board[i][j] = opponent;

                        // Call minimax recursively and choose
                        // the minimum value
                        best = Math.min(best, minimax(board,
                                depth + 1, !isMax));

                        // Undo the move
                        board[i][j] = "_";
                    }
                }
            }
            return best;
        }
    }

    // This will return the best possible
// move for the player
    static Move findBestMove(String[][] board) {
        int bestVal = -1000;
        Move bestMove = new Move();
        bestMove.row = -1;
        bestMove.col = -1;

        // Traverse all cells, evaluate minimax function
        // for all empty cells. And return the cell
        // with optimal value.
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                // Check if cell is empty
                if (board[i][j].equals("_")) {
                    // Make the move
                    board[i][j] = player;

                    // compute evaluation function for this
                    // move.
                    int moveVal = minimax(board, 0, false);

                    // Undo the move
                    board[i][j] = "_";

                    // If the value of the current move is
                    // more than the best value, then update
                    // best/
                    if (moveVal > bestVal) {
                        bestMove.row = i;
                        bestMove.col = j;
                        bestVal = moveVal;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return bestMove;
    }

    public void setBoard(String[][] Board){
        this.board = Board;
        Move bestMove = findBestMove(board);

        PlayerVersusComputer playerVersusComputer = new PlayerVersusComputer();
        playerVersusComputer.setRow(bestMove.row);
        playerVersusComputer.setCol(bestMove.col);
    }
}
```

I'm expecting a return integer (row and col) from the `Minimax.java` to the `PlayerVersusComputer.java` in this code snippet.

> PlayerVersusComputer.java

```
String buttonID = getResources().getResourceEntryName(v.getId()); //button_ij
        int pointerOne = Integer.parseInt(buttonID.substring(7, buttonID.length()-1)); //obtain i
        int pointerTwo = Integer.parseInt(buttonID.substring(buttonID.length()-1)); //obtain j

        if (player1Turn) {
            ((Button) v).setText("x");
            board[pointerOne][pointerTwo] = "x";
        } else {
            ((Button) v).setText("o");
            board[pointerOne][pointerTwo] = "o";
            checkBestMove();
        }

 protected void checkBestMove() {
        minimax.setBoard(board);
        row = getCol();
        col = getRow();
        tvAI.setText(row+"R"+" "+col+"C");
    }
```

This is the board Array. The board will "update" itself every time I pressed the `((Button) v).setText("x");` or `("o")`, then passed to Minimax.java when it's O's turn.

```
String[][] board = {{"_","_","_"},
                        {"_","_","_"},
                        {"_","_","_"}};
```

Since the `row` and `col` is not returned to the `checkBestMove()` function (I'm not sure if it's not returned or just can't "update" itself), the `tvAI.setText` keeps saying "0R0C" instead of updating itself (to 2R2C, then 0R1C, etc).

Update to the `row` and `col` are expected because the `tvAI.setText` is intended to suggest the player's next move. So why it's not updating?

Answer (score 0):

In function `setBoard` is the call of `findBestMove(board);` but the return value of type `Move` is ignored. Maybe you can assign it to a variable.

```
this.bestMove = findBestMove(board);
```

Comment: Edited the snippet there, so now it's `Move bestMove = findBestMove(board)`, then I declared an Object for `PlayerVersusComputer` class to pass the `bestMove.row` and `bestMove.col` to the setter-getter in that class. Still not working.